# Use a variable name for a block's name in Jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following template "base.html"

```
{% set list_of_ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] %}
{% for id in list_of_ids %}
  <div class="content">
    {% block id %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to do this and in another template "id1.html"

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block id1 %}
   <p>This is my content for id1 block! Different from id2 and id3 blocks</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you give a reason why you would want this?

Comment: I don't think there's no reason to do this at all.

Comment: We have a skeleton flask app that allows people to dynamically generate navigation bars and tabs by passing a list of their tabs in a setup file. If its not possible, we can just write more of the same template code for each tab - I was just looking to minimize repeated setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Block names are already names, you can't assign them names from variables.

`include` can take variables. A solution would be to include different template names and define the templates themselves, rather than blocks in a template.

`base.html`:

```
{% for id in ids %}
    {% include 'id' ~ id ~ '.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

`id1.html`:

```
<p>id1 content</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It worth nothing but you can do it in "twig" - PHP version of Jinja2 engine.

```
{% for block_name in blocks %}
  {{ block(block_name) }}
{%endfor %}
```